# how to save data of five activities on click of a button in the fifth activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I tried using *Intent*. Intent works for two activities only. It won't work for multiple activities. Each activities has minimum five *Edittext*. What is the best way to achieve? Am using Eclipse tool.

Comment: Use shared preference for each activity in last activity get values from it.

Comment: Thanks _Suhas Bachewar_  .. Works fine and simple too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shared preference for each activity in last activity get values from it.